# What are the column names in wincachegrind?

Tags: php, xdebug, kcachegrind

With lots of efforts and tutorials I got xdebug/wincachegrind up and running but most tutorials end with "Now everythings working, enjoy".

Everythings working, but I don't get the column naming in the stats:

- what means Avg. Self (Average Self)?
- what means Cum.?
- what is Total self in opposite to Average Self?
- what is Total Cum in opposite to Average Cum?

I'm a bit confused that I did not find an appropriate answer, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Self = Time spend inside the code of that function itself.
- Cum. = Time spend in functions Self calls with it's self time (short for Cumulative).
- Avg vs. Total: Average is average time per call, Total is the total time spend in all calls.

Comment: Does "Time spend in functions self calls itself." mean: The code of the function + the code of functions that are called by the function?

Is this recursiv (the code of functions that are called by functions of the functions does count as well)?

Comment: No, that means cumulative. I only have an educated guess about recursion: Each call is a call on it's own.

Comment: Ok, given your answer and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093138/kcachegrind-interpretation-confusion

I guess it's fair to say that "Cum." means cumulative and has the same meaning as Incl. in kcachegrind.

Comment: @shredding: Yes, Incl. and Cum. is the same.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the amount of ram and cpu used by each function?

Comment: Hmm, I think I misunderstood the quantities that I am dealing with. I found that I could write at the end of each base script  "echo echo_memory_usage();" in order to get the amount of bytes used. So memory has a volume. But CPU is measured in how fast a process gets processed ?